# Нужна помощь с asyncio python

Tags: python, asyncio, telethon

пишу парсер с помощью asyncio.
Задача:
Необходимо получить данные каналов/групп/чат в телеграме и получить в них список сообщений.

Причем в случае получения определенной ошибки (задержка, связанная с превышением количества получения entity (информация о канале, чате и т.д) сроком на 24 часа, перекинуть задачи аккаунта другому аккаунту или в общую очередь (ведь разбор json, получение списка сообщений - это CPU-Bound - задача, поэтому ее необходимо выполнять в отдельном потоке).

Для работы использую библиотеку Telethon, которая уже написана с asyncio.

```
import logging
from telethon import TelegramClient, utils, sync, errors
from telethon.tl.types import PeerUser, PeerChat
from telethon import functions, types
import pandas as pd
import time
import re
import asyncio
from contextlib import suppress
import traceback

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
format = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s:%(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(format=format, level=logging.INFO)

queue_entity = asyncio.Queue()
numbers = []

def load_excel(output_filename):
   data = pd.read_excel(output_filename, 'Projects', dtype=str)
   for item in data["Telegram link"]:
      if item != "nan":
          queue_entity.put_nowait(item)

#Создание client по номеру
async def create_client(number):
    client = TelegramClient(number, api_id, api_hash)
    client.start()
    return client

#Запрос entity, result - это информация о канале, чате и т.д
async def parse_entity(entity, client):
    print(entity)
    try:
        print("Успешно")
        return await client(functions.channels.GetFullChannelRequest(
                channel=entity
            ))

    except TypeError:
        try:
            return await client(functions.users.GetFullUserRequest(
                id=entity
            ))
        except TypeError:
            try:
                return await client(functions.messages.GetFullChatRequest(
                    chat_id=entity
                ))

            except:
                traceback.print_exc()

    except errors.UsernameInvalidError:
        print("Не найден пользователь, канал или чат")
    except errors.InviteHashExpiredError:
        print("Чата больше нет")
    except errors.InviteHashInvalidError:
        print("Ссылка приглашения не валидна")
    except ValueError:
        print("Невозможно получить entity. Для начала нужно вступить в группу или чат")
    except errors.FloodWaitError:
        print("Ожидание суток")

    return None




async def crawl(future):
    futures = []
    # Получаем из футуры ссылки
    numbers = await future
    # Выгребаем для каждой ссылки разметку страницы
    for account in asyncio.as_completed([create_client(number) for number in numbers]):
        while queue_entity.qsize() > 0:
            futures.append(asyncio.ensure_future(parse_entity(queue_entity.get_nowait(), await account)))
    if futures:
        print(await asyncio.wait(futures))

async def start_main(root):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    initial_future = loop.create_future()
    initial_future.set_result(root)
    await crawl(initial_future)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    load_numbers(filename_numbers) #Загрузка телефонов
    load_excel(filename_excel)     #Загрузка Excel
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.set_debug(True)
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(start_main(numbers))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        for task in asyncio.Task.all_tasks():
            task.cancel()
            with suppress(asyncio.CancelledError):
                loop.run_until_complete(task)
    finally:
        loop.close()
    log.info("Время работы: %s", time.time() - start)
```

Первоначально я хотел по мере получения соединения, создавать задачи со списка entity, но потом подумал, что у каждого аккаунта будет по списку (идет дублирование), поэтому переделал под очередь

C этим кодом выдает

```
  https://t.me/legendsroom
Необработанная ошибка 'coroutine' object is not callable
https://t.me/apxventures
Необработанная ошибка 'coroutine' object is not callable
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\events.py:88: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'as_completed.<locals>._wait_for_one' was never awaited
Coroutine created at (most recent call last)
  File "D:/Git/telegram/telegram_new.py", line 252, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(start_main(numbers))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 555, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 523, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1750, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 88, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "D:/Git/telegram/telegram_new.py", line 161, in start_main
    await crawl(initial_future)
  File "D:/Git/telegram/telegram_new.py", line 151, in crawl
    for account in asyncio.as_completed([create_client(number) for number in numbers]):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 536, in as_completed
    yield _wait_for_one()
  self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
({<Task finished coro=<parse_entity() done, defined at D:/Git/telegram/telegram_new.py:107> result=None created at D:/Git/telegram/telegram_new.py:153>,
 <Task finished coro=<parse_entity() done, defined at D:/Git/telegram/telegram_new.py:107> result=None created at D:/Git/telegram/telegram_new.py:153>,
...таких много сообщений
  File "D:/Git/telegram/telegram_new.py", line 252, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(start_main(numbers))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 555, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 523, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1750, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 88, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "D:/Git/telegram/telegram_new.py", line 161, in start_main
    await crawl(initial_future)
  File "D:/Git/telegram/telegram_new.py", line 151, in crawl
    for account in asyncio.as_completed([create_client(number) for number in numbers]):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 536, in as_completed
    yield _wait_for_one()
  await crawl(initial_future)
2018-12-24 16:47:32,640 INFO:Время работы: 6.054030656814575
```

Почему то проваливается в нижний Exception TypeError

**Update**

```
D:/Git/telegram/telegram_new.py:104: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'AuthMethods._start' was never awaited
Coroutine created at (most recent call last)
  File "D:/Git/telegram/telegram_new.py", line 250, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(start_main(numbers))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 555, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 523, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1750, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 88, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "D:/Git/telegram/telegram_new.py", line 104, in create_client
    client.start()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\auth.py", line 110, in start
    max_attempts=max_attempts
  client.start()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Git/telegram/telegram_new.py", line 250, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(start_main(numbers))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 568, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "D:/Git/telegram/telegram_new.py", line 159, in start_main
    await crawl(initial_future)
  File "D:/Git/telegram/telegram_new.py", line 151, in crawl
    futures.append(asyncio.ensure_future(parse_entity(await queue_entity.get(), account)))
TypeError: object str can't be used in 'await' expression
```

**Update 2**

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Git/telegram/telegram_new.py", line 106, in parse_entity
    chat_id=entity
TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not callable
D:/Git/telegram/telegram_new.py:143: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'as_completed.<locals>._wait_for_one' was never awaited
  await crawl(initial_future)
```

Comment: Дык это, `await queue_entity.get()` наверное?

Comment: @andreymal тогда выкидывает ошибку (смотри обновление)

Comment: У вае Queue синхронный что ли? Код явно неполный

Comment: @andreymal добавил код метода load_excel

Comment: Но какой у вас Queue, так и осталось непонятно

Comment: Кроме того, совершенно непонятно, откуда у вас взялось `Необработанная ошибка 'coroutine' object is not callable` — я в коде не нашёл строчки, которая могла бы отпечатать это. Такое чувство, будто код в вопросе по-прежнему не соответствует коду реальному

Comment: @Это я попытался определить что за ошибку кидает в TypeError, обновил код

Comment: Всё равно вы таким образом лишь замаскировали ошибку, используйте `traceback.print_exc()` вместо этого (и покажите уже, какой у вас Queue)

Comment: @andreymal не понял, а что вам не понятно с очередью? вам нужен список элементов в нем?

Comment: А с очередью то, что если я попытаюсь запустить код из вопроса у себя, то будет ошибка `NameError: name 'Queue' is not defined`, так что код в вопросе до сих пор неполный

Comment: @andreymal а все понял, from multiprocessing import Queue

Comment: То есть не только синхронный, но ещё и многопроцессный? Ну это вообще лютый перебор, изучите asyncio.Queue

Comment: Тем не менее независимо от Queue вы замаскировали TypeError ошибку и теперь непонятно где именно возникает, покажите traceback.print_exc()

Comment: @andreymal обновил код

Comment: Теперь непонятно что такое `functions.messages.GetFullChatRequest`. Такими темпами придётся кинуть в вас ссылкой [mcve] и закрыть вопрос по причине отсутствия оного. Хотя возможно, вы просто забыли await и там тоже

Comment: @andreymal обновил

Comment: @andreymal ну так что, не знаете в чем дело?

Comment: Я запутался окончательно. Во-первых, я перестал понимать, что из написанного в вопросе ещё актуально, а что уже нет. Во-вторых, я не понял — зачем вы импортировали `sync`, если вы собрались писать асинхронную программу? (В третьих, у telethon отвратительнейшая документация, и я там ни черта не понимаю, потому что все примеры синхронные; с синхронными примерами мой внутренний телепат отказывается отлаживать в уме асинхронную программу, увы)

Comment: Блин, судя по документации, этот telethon наполовину синхронный, наполовину асинхронный. Я отказываюсь мириться с таким франкенштейном; видимо, придётся ждать кого-то имеющего больший опыт в telethon

Comment: @andreymal, ладно, пошел сам пытаться разобраться